# Rails _path helper generating path with format not id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my routes.rb I have:

```
  resources :aquariums do
    resources :management_roles
    resources :graphs
    resources :animals
  end
  get 'aquarium', to: 'aquariums#show', :as => :aquarium
```

The reason for the last get is I have the notion of "current aquarium" in my app.  If, say, current_aquarium is set to 1, then in my controller's 'show' action '/aquarium' gets the same rendering as '/aquariums/1' with code like

```
@aquarium_id = params[:id] || current_aquarium.id
```

Now, and I'm assuming this is thanks to this different routing, this code:

```
<%= link_to aquarium.name, aquarium %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to aquarium.name, aquarium_path(aquarium) %>
```

Generates paths like this:

```
/aquarium.1
```

where I'd typically expect:

```
/aquariums/1
```

Right?

Per request... here's what `rake routes | grep aquar` yields:
(I'm assuming it's that very last route that is messing things up, but I would have thought that it would process these in order.  And, just FYI, I originally had that route at the top.  Moved it to the bottom assuming it would fix).

```
    aquarium_management_roles GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/management_roles(.:format)          management_roles#index
                              POST   /aquariums/:aquarium_id/management_roles(.:format)          management_roles#create
 new_aquarium_management_role GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/management_roles/new(.:format)      management_roles#new
edit_aquarium_management_role GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/management_roles/:id/edit(.:format) management_roles#edit
     aquarium_management_role GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/management_roles/:id(.:format)      management_roles#show
                              PUT    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/management_roles/:id(.:format)      management_roles#update
                              DELETE /aquariums/:aquarium_id/management_roles/:id(.:format)      management_roles#destroy
              aquarium_graphs GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/graphs(.:format)                    graphs#index
                              POST   /aquariums/:aquarium_id/graphs(.:format)                    graphs#create
           new_aquarium_graph GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/graphs/new(.:format)                graphs#new
          edit_aquarium_graph GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/graphs/:id/edit(.:format)           graphs#edit
               aquarium_graph GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/graphs/:id(.:format)                graphs#show
                              PUT    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/graphs/:id(.:format)                graphs#update
                              DELETE /aquariums/:aquarium_id/graphs/:id(.:format)                graphs#destroy
             aquarium_animals GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/animals(.:format)                   animals#index
                              POST   /aquariums/:aquarium_id/animals(.:format)                   animals#create
          new_aquarium_animal GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/animals/new(.:format)               animals#new
         edit_aquarium_animal GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/animals/:id/edit(.:format)          animals#edit
              aquarium_animal GET    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/animals/:id(.:format)               animals#show
                              PUT    /aquariums/:aquarium_id/animals/:id(.:format)               animals#update
                              DELETE /aquariums/:aquarium_id/animals/:id(.:format)               animals#destroy
                    aquariums GET    /aquariums(.:format)                                        aquariums#index
                              POST   /aquariums(.:format)                                        aquariums#create
                 new_aquarium GET    /aquariums/new(.:format)                                    aquariums#new
                edit_aquarium GET    /aquariums/:id/edit(.:format)                               aquariums#edit
                     aquarium GET    /aquariums/:id(.:format)                                    aquariums#show
                              PUT    /aquariums/:id(.:format)                                    aquariums#update
                              DELETE /aquariums/:id(.:format)                                    aquariums#destroy
                     aquarium GET    /aquarium(.:format)                                         aquariums#show
```

Thanks in advance!

Greg

Comment: Greg can you post the routes for aquariums? Some thing like "rake routes | grep aquarium"

Comment: Routes posted above.  Thanks!

Comment: Greg you are correct the routes are applied from top to bottom, so the first to match is the first executed but i guess that the problem resides in the name of the new routes, try setting for debug it's name to something else (change the :as => : aquarium )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change that last route from this:

```
get 'aquarium', to: 'aquariums#show', :as => :aquarium
```

to this:

```
get 'aquarium', to: 'aquariums#show', :as => :current_aquarium
```

The problem is that you have to routes named the same thing:

```
aquarium GET    /aquariums/:id(.:format)    aquariums#show
aquarium GET    /aquarium(.:format)         aquariums#show
```

If you make the change above then that second route will not match when you make those link to calls...  as it stands now, the second one is matching and like the route says is using your argument as the :format.

If you do make this change, you may need to tweak some things if you are intentionally linking to 'current_aquarium'.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!  I'd vote that up but don't have enough status.  Thanks Immendes too.