# Named routes inserting a . instead of a /

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, rails-routing

I've been having trouble with named routes in rails 4 ([Named route for non resource nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940065/named-route-for-non-resource-nesting)).

I've moved onto something else, but still struggling with the same problem of named routes for non resource urls.

This is my route from `rake routes`:

```
         GET    /messages/:id/report/:reply_token(.:format)     messages#report
messages POST   /messages(.:format)                             messages#create
```

and my routes.rb

```
resources :messages, only: [:create] do
  member do
    get 'report/:reply_token', :action => 'report'#, :as => :message
  end
end
```

Because of the problem I had in my post linked at the top, I'm trying to get a url to the /messages/:id/report/:reply_token route by doing the following:

```
"#{messages_url(@message, :host => "localhost:3000")}/report/#{@message.reply_token}"
```

But it's giving me this:

```
http://localhost:3000/messages.110/report/6bBw22TdaRYcQ3iVzW1ZwA
```

Why is there a . between the 'messages' and the '110' (message_id)?

Instead of @message, I've also tried @message.id in the `messages_url()`. I've also tried this: `report_message_path(message_id: @message.id, reply_token: @message.reply_token)` but got the same error as in my question linked above. I've also tried `message_url()` instead but it gives `undefined method 'message_url'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up routes. `messages_url` is to generate a URL for `create` action which does not have ID in its route. Rails assumes `110` is the format and uses the second route (which is named as `messages`)

```
messages POST   /messages(.:format)
```

As a solution, name your route like this and also add show action

```
resources :messages, only: [:create,:show] do
  member do
    get 'report/:reply_token', :action => 'report' , :as => :custom_message
  end
end
```

And,

```
custom_message_url(@message, :host => "localhost:3000")
```

More about naming routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes).

Answerd here already - [Rails _path helper generating path with format not id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172729/rails-path-helper-generating-path-with-format-not-id)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What does adding the show action give me? I don't actually have a show use case. So, is this the standard way to add non-resourceful actions to a controller? It doesn't seem very restful to me.

Comment: does it work without the `show` action? since `report/reply_token` is under `messages/:id` which is the URL of show action, I thought it is required. Try and let me know.

Comment: It does work without the `show` action. Without the show action, I got a nice route called `report_message` which then works very nicely via `report_message_url(@message, @message.reply_token, :host => "localhost:3000")` Thanks for the help

Comment: I linked this answer for my previous unsolved problem too. This fixed both.